# Angular 6 - <a> href gets appended to base url

Tags: html, angular6

I have a list of users displayed in the table and each users has link which is displayed and can be navigated to.

```
<div class="inline-icon-text">
  <small class="text-muted d-md-none mr-3">Link</small>
  <a [attr.href]="candidate.url" target="_blank" [title]="candidate.url">
    <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Problem is, when I inspect link element it points to correct address but after clicking on it gets appended to app base url.

```
<a _ngcontent-c15="" target="_blank" href="www.test.sk" title="www.test.sk">...</a>
```

And after click it gets opened in the new tab with address **localhost:4200/www.test.sk**

What do I miss?

Comment: This might help you https://medium.com/@adrianfaciu/using-the-angular-router-to-navigate-to-external-links-15cc585b7b88

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Always prepend your absolute external links with protocol or `//` shortcut for `http://` OR `https://` depending on your app's protocol.

```
<div class="inline-icon-text">
  <small class="text-muted d-md-none mr-3">Link</small>
  <a [attr.href]="'//' + candidate.url" target="_blank" [title]="candidate.url">
    <i class="material-icons">open_in_new</i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Browsers treat URLs as relative by default to facilitate in-app navigation.

As a side note, this behavior is not Angular-specific; other frameworks and plain sites behave exactly the same

Comment: Thanks, I expected it to work similar as [routerLink], with array of string/params. Using + sign is little bit confusing

Comment: This simply sets a string atrribute, so `+` means  usual JS string concatenation. `routerLink` is different because it's a directive with additional logic. HTH

Comment: Could you tell me why it happens?

Comment: @AliAbbaszade I don't understand, which parts are you asking about?

Comment: @TomaszBłachut I mean why does the URL change automatically when I don't put `//` before my address?

Comment: @AliAbbaszade URL syntax is complex & many parts can be omitted. Put simply, default behavior is the same as in your terminal: `cd projects` goes to child directory, and link pointing to `www.example.com` points to child resource relative to current one. Now single slash `/` makes URL relative to computer root dir, and double slash `//` makes URL relative to the root of the Internet if something like this even exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL HTH

Comment: Ok,but I have `www.example.com` URL for href attribute and there isn't single slash,is it related to base tag in index.html?

Comment: @TomaszBłachut what if I want to open a pure-css popup in angular? like this: `href="#open-modal"` or [ https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO ]

Comment: @OmidAtaollahi those are called fragments and should work as you've written

Comment: @TomaszBłachut I thought so. but angular adds `http://example.com/ ` to it, and gives me `http://example.com/#open-modal`. Any ideas?

Comment: @OmidAtaollahi Turns out that presence of  `base` HTML element changes behavior of fragments and Angular add `base` so in your case `http://example.com/` gets prepended.

Comment: @TomaszBłachut what will happen if the user writes in input for example `https://google.com` how would be the reaction `a href` tag ?
Because I have added your answer and it works for `www.something` and `something.com` but if I add `https://something.com` then the link it won't work.
Do you have any idea ?